# Child combinator applied to parent in production

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack

For my React application I have a small example node with the following structure:

```
<div className='main'>
      <input/>
</div>
```

For my CSS, I have the following:

```
.main > input {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

When debugging, it works as intended and the input is blue. However when the application is published, it does not display as intended. Instead the CSS shows this:

```
.main {
    background-color: blue;
}
.main > input {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

I have no other CSS files that would have the additional CSS.
Is this an issue with the way Webpack is processing files for production? Or is this a side effect of child combinators I wasn't aware of? Or is there somewhere else I should be looking for the root cause of this issue?

Comment: No, there is no such thing like side effect in child combinators. It seems like is been apply in some root component or main.css file adding such style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give  a class or id, and change the css through that.

```css
#id1 {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div className='main'>
  <input id='id1' />
</div>
```